# Python: How to move index in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to move all entries in a dict from i to i+1. Also I want to double the first entry in order to modify entry 0 later.

What I tried:

```
a={}
a[0]={}
a[1]={}
a[0][1]='a_0_1'
a[1][1]='a_1_1'
b = a.copy()
c = {}
for i in range(0, len(b)):     
  c[i+1]=b[i]
c[0]=b[0]   
c[0][1] = 'c_0_1'
```

I get results that I completely fail to understand. The entries are changed in all dicts. Why is that happening?

Comment: `a.copy()` makes a *shallow* copy. It doesn't copy the sub-dicts — it just copies references to them. If you search here for deep copy dictionary you'll find lots of good advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = {key + 1 : value for key, value in a.items()}
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: my bad, you have to iterate through a.items(), edited it

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. What is the name of the construct you are using?

Comment: dictionary comprehension, this also works for lists and is a core concept of modern python development

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Meyer pointed out, you may substitute `a.copy()` with `a.deepcopy()` to avoid `b` being a shallow copy of `a`. Note that `deepcopy`, as well as as `copy`, is in the `copy` module.